# Python dictionary subelements to list

Tags: python, list, variables, dictionary

I have a dictionary like the following:

```
d = {"result": {"page": "1", "games": {"game": {"id": "2016", "name": "Exemple"}}}}
```

I would like to group all sub-values of `d['result']['games']['game']` in a list, like:

```
d = {"result": {"page": "1", "games": {"game": [{"id": "2016", "name": "Exemple"}]}}}
```

How can I do this programmatically, modifying my dict variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d['result']['games']['game'] = [d['result']['games']['game']]`

and if you want to add another element

`d['result']['games']['game'].append({some other dict})`